# Change the CT number in a DICOM image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am trying to change the CT numbers (or Hounsfield unit, HU) in DICOM images using MATLAB, i.e. interpolate CT number from -1000 to -500 to one value (-750).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read in the image data, and the header:

```
fileName = 'image000.dcm';
img = dicomread(fileName);
imgHdr = dicominfo(fileName);
```

Patch the intensities:

```
img(img>=-1000 & img<=-500) = -750;
```

Save new file:

```
[~,base,ext] = fileparts(fileName);
dicomwrite(img,[base '_patched.dcm'],imgHdr,'CreateMode','Copy')
```

---

Say you have several ranges to patch:

```
upperVals = [-500     0  500];
lowerVals = [-1000 -500    0];
newVals =   [-750  -250  250];
```

You can use `bsxfun` with the less-than or equal and greater-than or equal operators:

```
masks = bsxfun(@ge,img(:),lowerVals(:).') & bsxfun(@le,img(:),upperVals(:).');
for i=1:numel(newVals), img(find(masks(:,i))) = newVals(i); end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I want to do many patches ( from -1000 to -500 = -750, and -500 to 0 = -250, and from 0 to 500 = 250, etc ) for many images (99 images), what is the quick way to do it ? Thanks

Comment: @Turki See my update with `bsxfun`.  Does that work?

Comment: I did :), but I've got a problem which is that the images that I got have significant scattered radiation, so at the edge of the patient, it gives a high CT number like if it were a bone region (which is only tissue). So I can define the coordinates of the bony region using the number of voxel in x and y for all the slices. i.e. from x=100 to x=170 consider it as 250 but before x=100 and after x=170 make it -250 for all y. But I don't know how to do that !? Sorry I bothered you with that ( new for MATLAB)

Comment: For the issue of spatially-varying intensity transformation, I'd formulate a new question, to get a better answer and for added value to the community.

Comment: Thanks Chappjc for your time